# domain design in grails for related things

Tags: database, grails, dns

using Grails 1.1.1

I have domain in Grails Person. Person can be related to another Person buut they can be stand alone. 
this is like:

I have A as my friend 
and A have me as his friend

B can be stand alone (not having friend)

should I type

```
Person {
 belongsTo = [friend:Person]
 hasMany = [persons:Person]

 constraints {
   friend(nullable:true)
 } 

}
```

and how to delete A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the friend property? Don't you just want a person to have zero to many friends?

```
Person {
 hasMany = [friends:Person]
}
```

Comment: can I have like this : 

Person person1 = new Person();
.... details and saving object ... 

Person person2 = new Person();

person1.addFriends(person2);

should I addFriend from person2 ?
like person2.addFriends(person1) ?